# Why can I drop an object with a 'static lifetime?

Tags: rust

I have the following code where I am storing an `App` inside a `Mutex` and an `Arc` but I also want to be able to swap this `App` out at any point during runtime. And the following code seems to work just fine.

However, even though the `App` is marked `'static` inside the static declaration and inside the `set_app` function, I am able to swap the underlying `App` out without issue. Plus the original `App` inside the `Mutex` gets dropped, even though it was marked `'static`.

Apologies as I'm new to Rust but clearly I'm missing something. In my mind if an object is able to go out of scope and be dropped it isn't `'static`. Why does this work?

[Source](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d91fc35e5ce254750c74c7f728ff11d):

```rust
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref APP: Arc<Mutex<App<'static>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(App { name: "App" }));
}

pub struct App<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Drop for App<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("DROPPING {}", self.name)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("CURRENT {}", APP.lock().unwrap().name);

    // Drops "App1"
    *APP.lock().unwrap() = App { name: "App2" };
    
    println!("CURRENT {}", APP.lock().unwrap().name);
    
    // Drops "App2"
    set_app(App { name: "App3" });
    
    println!("CURRENT {}", APP.lock().unwrap().name);
}

fn set_app(app: App<'static>) {
    *APP.lock().unwrap() = app;
}
```

Output:

```
CURRENT App
DROPPING App
CURRENT App2
DROPPING App2
CURRENT App3
```

Comment: And BTW, prefer [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell) over `lazy_static` - its API is going to be integrated into std.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `'static` lifetime *does not* mean "this value will live for the entire duration of the program". It means "this value *can* live for the entire duration of the program". That is, it does not contain any references that will drop earlier. However, it is perfectly fine to drop a `'static` object.

See also: [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions: if `T: 'static` then `T` must be valid for the entire program](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program).

For example, `String` is `'static` because it does not point to any external resource - thus, *if you don't drop it*, it'll live happily until the end of the program. However, we drop and free `String`s all the time - it is just that if I have a `String`, *and I don't drop it*, it won't be dropped behind my back, unlike say a reference.